# compare files pooutput.txt file & apdca-sd-rt01.txt files find exact line found in apdca-sd-rt01.txt then print ok else not ok

Tags: bash, shell

2 files to be compared.
pooutput.txt & apdca-sd-rt01.txt are the files.

pooutput.txt contains :

```
323   Po323(SU)   Eth      LACP      Eth1/14(P)   Eth2/14(P)
345   Po345(SU)   Eth      LACP      Eth1/15(P)   Eth2/15(P)
367   Po367(SU)   Eth      LACP      Eth1/16(P)   Eth2/16(P)
```

apdca-sd-rt01.txt contains :

```
323   Po323(SU)   Eth      LACP      Eth1/14(P)   Eth2/14(P)
345   Po345(SU)   Eth      LACP      Eth1/15(P)   Eth2/15(P)
367   Po367(SU)   Eth      LACP      Eth1/16(P)   Eth2/16(D)
```

So the expected to be printed "Not Ok" coz in the last line is Eth2/16(D) but it should have been Eth2/16(P)

diff , comm -23 , some grep types i have already tried

Tried this

```
[ $(grep -cxFf pooutput.txt <(sort -u apdca-sd-rt01.txt)) = $(sort -u pooutput.txt | wc -l) ] && 
  echo ok || 
  echo not ok
```

Tried this

```
  if grep -ow '323   Po323(SU)   Eth      LACP      Eth1/14(P)   Eth2/14(P)
345   Po345(SU)   Eth      LACP      Eth1/15(P)   Eth2/15(P)
367   Po367(SU)   Eth      LACP      Eth1/16(P)   Eth2/16(P)' "apdca-sd-rt01.txt";then
echo Ok
else
echo Not OK 
fi
```

```
diff -U $(wc -l < pooutput.txt) pooutput.txt apdca-sd-rt01.txt | sed -n 's/^-//p' > fileC
```

```
diff -Ebv --new-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format="" <(sort pooutput.txt) <(sort apdca-sd-rt01.txt)
```

But for such small change from P to D , it dint help

Expected should be " Not ok " since lines are not matching exactly. Some how none of the above ones are working fine.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your first example prints out "Not OK" for me. But I would keep it simple, for example:

```
! diff pooutput.txt apdca-sd-rt01.txt > /dev/null && echo "NOT OK"
```

This will print "NOT OK" if diff finds a difference in the two files provided.